# Customize DatePicker spinner

Tags: android, datepicker, spinner, customization

I'm pretty new to Kotlin & Android, and I have to create a DatePicker, ideally in Spinner mode, but I have too customize a bit this spinner. I neeed to hide the top and bottom of each spinners (to see only the current value), and but some background.

I'm pretty fine for the background feature, but I have no idea to how to hide the spinners overflow.

Can't find any suggest on the net so I'm coming here.

Here is the style i need to achieve:

[image]

Thanks.